# Is there any technology for dynamic assignment of execution context for programs that target many platforms with widely varying runtime performance?

Tags: distributed-computing

This may very well be nothing new and probably exists, but I've never learned about it and would like to.

The simplest way to be more specific is just to give an example.

I was on the bus and downloaded a Text to Speech appliation onto my Android phone.

I know that the speech synthesizer might run on my phone but probably runs on a remote server.

In the near future I bet the processors in phones will go up and some people will have phones that could do the work but some will not.

In the scenario I just describe, the ideal situation might be if the execution environment dynamically pulled code to locally execute and/or pushed code back to be remotely executed.

I realize there are plently of frameworks for remote object calling, but do any of them pre-suppose the above?

Answer (score 2):

Agent frameworks are designed to support agents being moved from machine to machine, sometimes they do it automatically.

JADE http://jade.tilab.com/ is an agent framework that will run on android

Comment: does that link work for anyone?